# Display spaces in menu-bar on Mavericks

Tags: macos, spaces, menu-bar

How to display the current space number in the menu-bar with Mavericks? Like it had been possible in previous versions of Mac OSX?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidently the [answer I got for another problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293290/57046) solved this one, too:

[TotalSpaces2](https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/navigation2) displays the current space number in the menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get just the space number without all the overhead from using TotalSpaces, there is a nice little app on github: [SpaceId](https://github.com/dshnkao/SpaceId)
which will add the space number to the menu bar like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [SpaceInfo](https://github.com/davidpurnell/SpaceInfo) to retrieve the current space number from the command line using

```
SpaceInfo --active-space
```

This information can then be displayed in the menu bar using an application like [xbar](https://github.com/matryer/xbar)