# Cycle through spaces in Mavericks

Tags: macos, spaces

On Snow Leopard you could "jump" from the last space to the first space by hitting cmd+right arrow.

How to do this in Mavericks?

Comment: Solutions for macOS 11 or newer can be found at https://powerusers.codidact.com/posts/287898

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but the app TotalSpaces2 seems to provide this feature:

https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/navigation2

[image]

Caveat:

In newer versions of macOS they require you to disable SIP when installing.

Comment: Thank you! The first constructive answer I got for this question!

Comment: It even solves another question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152757/display-spaces-in-menu-bar-on-mavericks In case you want to post an answer there ...

Comment: Go for it. Get the pointses!

Answer (score 1):

They don't cycle any more, last to first.

I've found the best solution is to assign a key command to every Space you use & go directly to the one you want.

I use Ctrl/number.

Additional irritation is that Fullscreen apps insert themselves into the 'list' of Spaces, but cannot be called directly.

Answer (score -2):

To accommodate for not cycling anymore, you can enter a command for **Switch to Desktop 1**, i.e. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

[image: mission control keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: This is not cyclic like the question asked. This does not allow you to be on the last space and press `⌃ + →` to cycle back to the first space (at least on Mavericks).

Comment: @aglasser Ah, didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: I did not down vote you, by the way.

Comment: @aglasser No worries, that's what the button is for.